# What Julia code is as fast as this python (scipy.integrate)

Tags: julia

I want to compute a triple integral where another variable is included in the integration range.
But my Julia code is 1000x slower than that of Python. What code should it be instead?

I somehow coded the following in python.

```
import scipy.integrate as spi

integrand = lambda x,y,z: x**2 + 2*y + z**2

result, err = spi.quad(lambda z: spi.quad(lambda y: spi.quad(lambda x: integrand(x, y, z), 0, y**2)[0], 0, 10)[0], 2, 4)
```

and my Julia counterpart is

```
using QuadGK

integrand0 = (x,y,z) -> x^2 + 2*y + z^2

integrand1 = (y,z) -> quadgk((x) -> integrand0(x,y,z), 0,y^2)[1]
    
integrand2 = (z) -> quadgk((y) -> integrand1(y,z), 0,10)[1]

result, err = quadgk((z) -> integrand2(z), 2, 4)
```

however, this Julia code is 1000x slower than the python!
This is even slower (10000x) if I write it as a single line like the python one

```
result, err = quadgk((z)->quadgk((y)-> quadgk((x)->integrand0(x,y,z), 0,y^2)[1], 0,10)[1], 2, 4)
```

It's a huge disappointment as I started learning Julia after hearing about its speed. What would be a comparably fast Julia code for this?
Thank you!

Comment: Are the tolerances the same?

Comment: If I just wrap it in a function, e.g. `f() = quadgk(...)` then it's around 10x faster than python for me. Seems to spend all its time in compilation otherwise

Comment: For me, `@time` reports 99.99% compilation time, which is a factor of 10,000. When wrapping in a function, after compilation, it takes 30us. So, how do you want to use this? Do you need to evaluate the same integrand for different limits, or different integrands too? Or is it just a one-off?

Comment: Another thing is that solving multi-dimensional integrals with nested 1D integration is not efficient, proper multi-dimensional integral techniques should be faster. Also, numerical tolerance levels will strongly influence the calculation time, so that should be the same for Julia and Python.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the comments, wrapping the `quadgk` call in a function seems to solve the issue. But an even faster (and more accurate I assume) way would be to use a package for multidimensional integrals, like HCubature.jl. For example:

```
f(x, y, z) = ((x * y^2)^2 + 2y + z^2) * y^2
hcubature(splat(f), (0, 0, 2), (1, 10, 4))
```

Since `hcubature` integrates over a rectangular region you need to do a change of variables to integrate x from 0 to y^2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! About the wrapping, does it mean wrapping everything by 'function f() ... end'? It is faster only after the second run. It takes even longer the first time after the parameter/equation is changed. I want to calculate a more complex equation of this kind with varying parameters. Do I not understand?

Comment: Well the first time is when compilation happens, so you can expect that to be slower. I'd wrap the entire computation in a function, and have arguments for the parameters you want to vary. After the first run, calls to f with different parameters should be similar in speed. If you want to change the integrand entirely then you'll probably have to recompile